# Реализация realloc

Tags: c, инспекция-кода, realloc

В FreeRTOS есть только `malloc` и `free`, но нет `calloc` и `realloc`. Мне нужен `realloc` и я попытался сам его реализовать. Всё ли здесь верно? Сам модуль управления памятью можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/cjlano/freertos/blob/76303e704cf924fa514abace4529ba8b9cd5b515/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang/heap_2.c).

```
void *pvPortRealloc(void *ptr, size_t s)
{
uint8_t *puc = ( uint8_t * ) ptr;
BlockLink_t *pxLink;
void *newBlock;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        puc -= heapSTRUCT_SIZE;
        pxLink = (void*) puc;
        vTaskSuspendAll();
        {
            newBlock = pvPortMalloc(s);
            memcpy(newBlock, ptr, pxLink->xBlockSize);
            vPortFree(ptr);         
        }
        xTaskResumeAll();
        return newBlock;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

Вот новая версия, созданная после замечаний AnT.

```
void *pvPortRealloc(void *ptr, size_t s)
{
uint8_t *puc = ( uint8_t * ) ptr;
BlockLink_t *pxLink;
void *newBlock;
extern void memcpy( void*, void*, size_t );
size_t blockSize;

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        newBlock = pvPortMalloc(s);
    }
    else
    {
        puc -= heapSTRUCT_SIZE;
        pxLink = (void*) puc;
        blockSize = pxLink->xBlockSize - heapSTRUCT_SIZE;
        if (s == 0)
        {
            newBlock = NULL;
        }
        else if (s > blockSize)
        {
            vTaskSuspendAll();
            {
                newBlock = pvPortMalloc(s);
                if (newBlock != NULL)
                {
                    memcpy(newBlock, ptr, blockSize);
                    vPortFree(ptr);         
                }
            }
            xTaskResumeAll();

        }
        else //s < blockSize
        {
            vTaskSuspendAll();
            {
                size_t newBlockSize = s + heapSTRUCT_SIZE + ( portBYTE_ALIGNMENT - ( s & portBYTE_ALIGNMENT_MASK ) );
                //if right segment is to few, do nothing
                if (pxLink->xBlockSize - newBlockSize > heapSTRUCT_SIZE)
                {
                    //split current block
                    pxLink->xBlockSize = newBlockSize;
                    BlockLink_t *blockToFree = (void*)((uint8_t*)pxLink + pxLink->xBlockSize);
                    blockToFree->xBlockSize = blockSize + heapSTRUCT_SIZE - pxLink->xBlockSize;
                    //free second part
                    prvInsertBlockIntoFreeList( ( ( BlockLink_t * ) blockToFree ) );
                    xFreeBytesRemaining += blockToFree->xBlockSize;
                }
                newBlock = ptr;
            }
            xTaskResumeAll();           
        }
    }
    return newBlock;
}
```

Comment: А где освобождение памяти при `s = 0`? Что будет если размер равен предыдущему?

Comment: не надо делать suspend-resume. Внутри malloc/free оно уже есть, больше не нужно.

Comment: @AlexeyEsaulenko, почему? Ведь в `pvPortMalloc` и `vPortFree` это делается.

Comment: Пожалуй, надо было подробнее писать. В malloc / free Вы работаете с общим пулом памяти, в который могут быть одновременные обращения из разных потоков. А тут все переменные принадлежат одному потоку.

Comment: Да, и ещё почитайте http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html про разные типы heap'ов. Та реализация, которую Вы взяли, при активном выделении-освобождении загадит всю память.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Бросается в глаза, что ваш `realloc` сразу возвращает null-указатель если на вход пришел null-указатель. Это уже неправильно. Стандартный `realloc(NULL, size)` должен работать как `malloc(size)`.
2. А где проверка на то, что `s` может быть *меньше*, чем исходный размер? С чего вы взяли, что можно вот просто так взять и сделать

   ```
   memcpy(newBlock, ptr, pxLink->xBlockSize);
   ```

   ?
3. (Вариация 2) При запросе нулевого размера стандартный `realloc` имеет implementation-defined поведение с оговоренным набором вариантов. У вас, если `0` попадет в `pvPortMalloc`, то `pvPortMalloc` вернет null-указатель. Вы к этому не готовы.
4. А где обработка неудавшегося выделения памяти?

---

После исправления:

При вызове `realloc` с размером `0` стандартный `realloc` не гарантирует освобождение старой памяти (это не говорится явно в стандарте, но [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) утверждает, что стандарт следует интерпретировать именно так). Ваша реализация формально вписывается в это поведение. Но возможно элегантнее было бы вместе с возвращением null-указателя таки освободить старый блок памяти. Возможно...

Comment: Вмесот `memcpy` лучше использовать `memmove`. При использовании `memmove` область памяти может перекрыватся.

Comment: @Yaroslav, здесь нет. Блоки, выделенные с помощью `malloc`, не перекрываются.